# How to calculate from a dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
import operator

with open("D://program.txt") as f:
Results = {}
for line in f:
    part_one,part_two = line.split()
    Results[part_one] = part_two


c=sum(int(Results[x]) for x in Results)
r=c/12
d=len(Results)
F=max(Results.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
u=min(Results.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
print ("Number of entries are",d)
print ("Student with HIGHEST mark is",F)
print ("Student with LOWEST mark is",u)
print ("Avarage mark is",r)
Results = [ (v,k) for k,v in Results.items() ]
Results.sort(reverse=True)
for v,k in Results:
print(k,v)

import sys

orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = open('D://programssr.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f
print ('Number of entries are',d)
print ("Student with HIGHEST mark is",F)
print ("Student with LOWEST mark is",u)
print ("Avarage mark is",r)
for v,k in Results:
print(k,v)

sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()
```

I want to read a txt file but problem is it cant compute the results i want to write in a new file because of the NAMES and MARKS in file.if you remove them it works fine.i want to make calculations without removing NAMES and MARKS in txt file..Help what i am i doing wrong

```
NAMES   MARKS
Lux     95
Veron   70
Lesley  88
Sticks  80
Tipsey  40
Joe     62
Goms    18
Wesley  35
Villa   11
Dentist 72
Onty    50
```

Answer (score 0):

Just consume the first line using [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function, before looping over it:

```
with open("D://program.txt") as f:
    Results = {}
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        part_one,part_two = line.split()
        Results[part_one] = part_two
```

Note that file objects are iterator-like object (one shot iterable) and when you loop over them you consume the items and you have no access to them anymore.